# Firebase Spinner - Update Spinner Text on Selected Item

Tags: java, android, firebase, spinner, android-adapterview

I've seen similar Q&A on this and played around with several variations.  I'm trying to update the Spinner text, but nothing happens.

In the onCreate method I have two spinners:
1.) DCAccount2 (XML ID)
2.) NumofPayments(XML ID)

DC Account2 successfully pulls the query data from Firebase database and populates the drop down with the correct values I want to see.  But when I select the value I want, nothing happens.  The Spinner text is not updated.?.?

```
Spinner DC_Account_Spr = findViewById(R.id.DCAccount2);
DC_Account_Spr.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> DC_Array_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, user_debit_acct_DL);
DC_Array_Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
DC_Account_Spr.setAdapter(DC_Array_Adapter);

Spinner Num_Pymts_Spr = findViewById(R.id.NumofPayments);
Num_Pymts_Spr.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Num_Pymts_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Num_Payments, com.google.android.material.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Num_Pymts_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(com.google.android.material.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Num_Pymts_Spr.setAdapter(Num_Pymts_adapter);
```

Other relevant methods:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
    switch(parent.getId()) {
        case (R.id.DCAccount2):
            //This is where I think I am not capturing the selected item properly
            String Account_Selected_Str = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Account_Selected_Str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        case (R.id.NumofPayments):
            String Num_Payments_Str = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Num_Payments_Str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    return;
}
```

I've tried using setSelection and several variables, but still no luck

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No errors - compiles just fine.  Logcat doesn't give any helpful info either.  I think my "case (R.id.DCAccount2)" section isn't correct, because when a drop down value is selected, nothing happens or it's returning the position of the item selected, not the text value.

Comment: I added the toast message to the "case (R.id.DCAccount2)" so that i could see what it was coming up with after I select a value and no Toast message appears.  For the second case, it does work just fine.  So I'm pretty sure something is wrong with my logic (not syntax).  The difference is DCAccount2 spinner is pulling query data and setting the results of the query as the drop-down values.  NumofPayments has static integer values (1, 2, and 3).